# Upgrading to rails 3.1 broke rails server, getting weird error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After upgrading to rails 3.1 i am now getting this error after trying to run rails server:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing': undefined method `context_class' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

there are a bunch of other lines of failures too but i didn't want to paste all of them. here's my gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'activeadmin'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.4'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '0.1.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'meta_search'
gem 'sass-rails'

group :development do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.1'
    gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
    gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
end

group :test do 
    gem 'rspec', '2.0.1'
    gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
    gem 'autotest-fsevent', '0.2.4'
    gem 'autotest-growl', '0.2.9'
    gem 'autotest', '4.3.2'
    gem 'autotest-rails-pure', '4.1.0'
    gem 'spork', '0.8.4'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
end
```

here's the rest of the error:

```
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:68:in `establish_connection'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:60:in `establish_connection'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `on_load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:67:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/beatjunkie84/Desktop/ProjectX/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

what can i do ?

Comment: That exception should have more of a stacktrace. Could you show us that? That would provide much needed information to figure out what your error is.

Comment: @RyanBigg added the rest of the error, hope that helps.

Comment: It's a problem connecting to your db. Are you using sqlite3? Is the gem installed properly?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `rake rails:update`. Overwrite your files when it asks, but then review the changes and make sure you keep the ones you want to keep (so in the end you are keeping a merged result of their changes and yours).

This is what I did, and it fixed a similar error to yours.